# Javascript yes/no/maybe ask function

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I've started to learn programming using javascript. My aim is for the program to ask the user a set of yes/no questions. So far I've been using the prompt function for the asking but I wanted something less invasive, like a button. The problem is I can't get the program to wait for an answer to be picked without using a while loop, which freezes the program.
Is there a way to get the while loop to behave? If not what do I do?

Code( simplified, just function and buttons):

```
var currentAnswer = "unanswered"

function Change2Yes(){
    currentAnswer = "y"
}
function Change2No(){
    currentAnswer = "n"
}
function Change2Maybe(){
    currentAnswer = "m"
}

function question(x){
    document.write(x)
    while (currentAnswer != "y" && currentAnswer != "n" && currentAnswer != "m"){
        //do nothing THIS IS THE PART THAT FREEZES THE PROGRAM
    }
    if(currentAnswer == "y"){
        answerlist.push("y");
        latestAnswer="y";
    }
    else if(currentAnswer == "n"){
        answerlist.push("n");
        latestAnswer="n";
    }
    else if(currentAnswer== "m"){
        answerlist.push("m");
        latestAnswer="n";
    }

    currentAnswer= "unanswered"
}
```

```
<button id="btnYes" onclick="Change2Yes()">
    Yes
</button>
<button id="btnNo" onclick="Change2No()">
    No
</button>
<button id="btnMaybe" onclick="Change2Maybe()">
    Maybe
</button>
```

Thanks so much :)

Comment: You need to use events, bound to the buttons.

Comment: Isn't that onclick="Change2Maybe()" etc?

Comment: Yes, but the events need to drive the logic of the game. You cannot use an infinite `while` loop for this. JavaScript is single-threaded, and your while loop is blocking that thread.

Comment: Why are you using `while (currentAnswer != "y"`, it an infinite loop? May be you need `if (currentAnswer != "y" && ....) return; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use events. Add a listener for clicks, for example:

```
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'));

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', answer.bind(this, button.value));
});

function answer(currentAnswer) { ... };
```

The `answer` function will be called once a button is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/fWeq6/